# Regarding TIMP and MMP enzymes

Tags: cell-biology

Are there substances that can promote TIMP enzyme production, or MMP enzyme production or supression in tendons?

Are there medical tests that measure quantities of MMP and TIMP enzymes in tendons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question

Both enzymes, are components of Epidermal growth factor receptor (EGFR) signalling pathway.

MMP is a matrix metalloproteinase, that triggers EGFR signalling, this can be done by a mechanism called transactivation

[image: transactivation]

So, A signal from G-coupled receptor, or cytokine receptor could activate the cleavage of MMP,  then MMP converts to a ligand for EGFR activation

For example Angiotensin II type 1 receptor (AT1R) and type 2 receptor (AT2R) which are GPCR, there are evidence for crosstalk with EGFR, look for this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022282800912720). This could be linked with hypertension or inflamation. Also cancer, could trigger EGFR receptors by NMP's.

And finally tissue inhibitors of metalloproteinases (TIMPs) are the negative regulator of MMP's

This are only an overview of the whole biological process involving MMP, so I think there is no single answer to your question, but you can delimit the topic for a specific disease, and look for papers at google scholar.

Comment: Did you mean to make this community wiki?

Comment: Yes, because I do not have, the complete answer, and if someone could help to complete that or have more examples, can enhance the reply, I think this is a very interesting field to research. I'm finishing my MSc thesis in signal transduction, for a model like this.